# The comment is cut from a point

Tags: listings

I am writing an algorithm in LATEX un=sing sharelatex.com. I have written a long comment and it is cut from a point.

I have written this:

```
    %This is a LaTeX template for homework assignments
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

Function(A[1...n],x){
  ...............
   count=0;
   H(A[1...n],n);
   if (a==0){
       while (j<=n and A[j]<=0){
              ................
       }

       /* If there is at least one element that is equal to zero and at least one non-zero element then there are two elements with the desired property. In any other case the variable found is not changed.  */
       if (count!=0 and count!=n) found=1;
   }
   .............
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and it looks like that:

[image]

What could I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]

Function(A[1...n],x){
  ...............
   count=0;
   H(A[1...n],n);
   if (a==0){
       while (j<=n and A[j]<=0){
              ................
       }

       /* If there is at least one element that is equal to zero and at least one non-zero element then there are two elements with the desired property. In any other case the variable found is not changed.  */
       if (count!=0 and count!=n) found=1;
   }
   .............
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```